Arrays and sizeof() in C++
It is said that when an array is passed as a parameter to a function, it decays into a pointer and the length of the array needs to be passed as a parameter as well. This implies that the original array stored information about its size.
Indeed, sizeof(arr) inside a function body, where arr is an argument of the function, should return 8 (bytes), because that's the size of a pointer in a 64-bit machine. Meanwhile sizeof(arr), when arr is not a parameter, returns the actual size of the whole array in bytes.
#include <iostream>
void foo(int arr[]) {
  // prints 8
  std::cout << sizeof(arr) << "\n";
}

int main() {
  int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  // prints 20
  std::cout << sizeof(arr) << "\n";
  // prints 8
  foo(arr);
}

But the name of the array is already a pointer to its first element. arr[i] is just *(arr + i). This leads to a contradiction. Either:

The name of the array is not a pointer to its first element (as I was told). But then what is it? And if it's not a pointer, why is pointer arithmetic with it possible?
The name of the array really is a pointer to the first element. But then why does it keep different information than the pointer it decays into?


"The name of the array really is a pointer to the first element..." No, that is simply not true The name of an array represents an array not a pointer to its first element. In some contexts, the name of an array decays to pointer to its first element but that does not make the array to be a pointer.

It does not imply that the original array stored size information - the compiler knows the size of arrays at compile-time.

You got bamboozled by the types. int arr[] as a variable declared on the stack with an initializer is actually a int[N] for some N. int arr[] as a function parameter is actually a int*. Why? Because design mistakes were made.

" But then what is it? ...." It is an array! of type T [N]

Okay, this explains why sizeof() returns the actual size of the array. But if the name of the array represents an array is not a pointer, why is pointer arithmetic like *(arr+i) possible?

*"why is pointer arithmetic like (arr+i) possible?..." Because in certain contexts array decays to a pointer to its first element. Note only "in certain context" but not in all contexts.

The name of the array isn't anything at all; it is literally just a few characters of source code. Just like the name "Kotaka Danski" is not a person.

@user12002570 So, basically, arr is just a variable name for a variable of the array data type and in the expression *(arr + i), arr decays into a pointer, just like it decayed, when arr was passed as a parameter to the function?

arr + i is equivalent to &arr[0] + i; pointer decay occurs in more situations than argument-passing. Get a good book and don't trust rumours.

@KotakaDanski Yes exactly, arr is just a variable name for a variable of array data type.  Sometimes it decays to a pointer to its first element and sometime it does not. This is why we say "c++ is a context dependent language". Meaning of one construct may depend on where/how etc it is used.

Well, that turned out to be much simpler than I anticipated. I feel sorry for even creating the question, but using the search engine and even an LLM (Bing) didn't produce a straightforward explanation, unlike your comments did. Thanks. I am marking the answer as accepted, so that this question doesn't attract unnecessary attention anymore.

@KotakaDanski It's ok and is part of learning any language etc. Only when we ask question and clear our doubts we'll actually learn anything.

Thanks for the understanding and for your time (and to everyone else involved). I guess I had luck today, because other times a question immediately got downvoted and closed for asking obvious things. I kind of agree in this case as well, that this should have been obvious. On the other hand, sometimes I thought I understood something, because I had managed to produce an explanation for myself, only to accidentally discover months later that it wasn't true. This is one such case. I had never bothered going into such details, because what I already "knew" was "sufficient" to get a program going


This leads to a contradiction.

No it does not. In certain contexts, an array decays to a pointer to its first element. For example, one case where array does not decay to a pointer is decltype:
int arr[2];
decltype(arr) i;     //i is int[2] and array does not decay to a pointer here

Here is one example where it does decay to a pointer to its first element:
int arr[2]{};
auto j = arr; //j is int*; here array decays to int*

Another example where array does not decays is:
char arr[10]{};
auto k = sizeof(arr); // k is initialized with 10 and array  does not decay to pointer


Another other obvious case, arguably relevant in context of this question, where an array does not decay is as the operand of sizeof.   So, sizeof(arr) is sizeof(int[2]) which is (typically) not equal to sizeof(int *).
